# Bash have wait ignore signals

Tags: bash, signals

I am trying to run commands in the background in a shell script and `wait` for them at the end of the script so they don't get orphaned.  I also want to call a function when a signal is received but the signal kills my `wait` and the script ends.  How can I have `wait` ignore the signal and keep `wait`ing?  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=0

sigHandle()
{
    if [[ $num -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "trapped"
        ((num++))
    else
        echo "Already called trap"
    fi
}

trap 'sigHandle' SIGUSR1
sleep 12345 &
wait
```

I tried changing my trap to be `trap 'sigHandle; wait' SIGUSR1` but then my signal handling function doesn't get called after the 1st time.  This works but not sure if that is the right way to do it.

```
 while :; do
    wait
 done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `wait` in a loop, and continue if `wait` exits with status 158 (indicating it was interrupted by `SIGUSR1`):

```
sigusr1_no=30  # Mac OS X
# sigusr1_no=10  # Linux
trap 'sigHandle' SIGUSR1
sleep 12345 &
while :; do
    wait
    status=$?
    if [[ $status = $((sigusr1_no + 128)) ]]; then
        echo "USR1 handled, continuing"
        continue
    else
        break
    fi
done
```

In general, any status greater than 128 indicates that `wait` was interrupted by a received signal (which signal being the lower 8 bits of the status). You may want to handle different signals differently, but this gives you the framework for deciding whether to continue waiting for `sleep` to finish.

Comment: SIGUSR1 is nr 10, so 138, no?

Comment: The actual number used for `SIGUSR1` is platform-dependent. It is 10 in Linux, 30 in Mac OS X.

Comment: for portability use `sigusr1_no=$(kill -l SIGUSR1)`